# Elementary Statistics book using Chemistry Data Sets

Tags: references, chemometrics

I searched a lot but could not find an Elementary Statistics book using Chemistry data sets for examples and exercises. I would highly appreciate if someone point out me such books.

Comment: You will find a lot by typing "introduction to statistics for chemists" intoo google!

Answer (score 6):

[Here's](https://books.google.com/books?id=TUETAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=iupac%20statistics&source=bl&ots=c5AfEsqy-A&sig=wuUT9HgT8fUXd9mqTsbFnJF847o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bqpLVfadGIPEgwSv9oCIBg&ved=0CCAQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=iupac%20statistics&f=false) the list of readings for lab scientists, including chemists. It's from "Laboratory Statistics: Handbook of Formulas and Terms", Anders Kallner, Elsevier, Sep 6, 2013. See "Further readings" at the end.