# Statistics book recommendation for absolute beginners and non-mathematics people

Tags: self-study, references, intuition

Based on  [**this**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/170/free-statistical-textbooks) [**this**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63099/book-recommendations-for-beginners-about-probability-distributions) and [**this**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149854/elementary-statistics-book-using-chemistry-data-sets), but also looking for following specifications

1. For absolute beginners level, and easy type book.
2. **Easy to read (Less text, larger fonts)**.
3. **Not mathematically rigorous**.
4. More diagrams and high amount of visual explanations.
5. Intuitive explanations.
6. Comprehensible for non-mathematics people.

I am looking for the following topics to be covered (and for now not much more than that)-

1. Probability distributions with natural examples
2. Central tendency
3. Dispersion
4. Skewness, kurtosis
5. Corelation, regression etc.
6. Statistical tests (Chi square, F, Z, Student's T etc)
7. ANOVA, ANCOVA

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421/what-book-would-you-recommend-for-non-statistician-scientists , also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48347/any-suggestions-for-a-good-undergraduate-introductory-textbook-to-statistics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easiest book I have ever seen **Head First Statistics (A Brain Friendly Guide)**
Link:
https://www.amazon.de/dp/0596527586/?coliid=I3NFQSPYBP80Y2&colid=2JIYCWIVUT6C1&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it

This one is also a very good book with a lot of example. **Schaum's Outline of Probability and Statistics: 897 Solved Problems**
Link:https://www.amazon.de/Schaums-Outline-Probability-Statistics-Problems/dp/007179557X/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=1SL74D6EGB39G&dchild=1&keywords=probability+and+statistics+schaum&qid=1595533697&sprefix=probability+and+stat%2Caps%2C168&sr=8-1

Comment: Thank you these will help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

BIOS Instant notes in Mathematics and Statistics for Life Scientists  (https://www.amazon.in/Instant-Notes-Mathematics-Statistics-Scientists/dp/1859962920) could be greatly helpful.

Simple Statistics: A Course Book for the Social Sciences, by Francis Klegg https://www.amazon.in/Simple-Statistics-Course-Social-Sciences/dp/0521288029 might be of help

Statistics: Concepts and Fundamentals for Absolute Beginner, by Lewis Jack https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Statistics.html?id=QzkTwQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y might be helpful

Statistics for Beginners: Easy way to Learn Statistics Today: 100 Solved Equations to Easily Explain Statistics, by Deborah Oliver, [https://www.amazon.com/Statistics-Beginners-Solved-Equations-Explain/dp/1659945879](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1659945879) could be greatly helpful.